# Compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{x^2} - \cos x}{\sin^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of

$\dfrac{e^{x^2} - \cos x}{\sin^2 x}$

What I tried is as $x$ approaches $0$, $e^{x^2}$ tends to $1$ and so the numerator tends to $1-\cos x$ and after doing some trigonometric simplifications I got the answer as $\frac 12$.

Is this right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. The numerator also tends to 0 because $\cos(0) = 1$ and $e^0=1$.

Comment: There was $\frac{x}{2}$ before the edit, now there's $x^2$. Anyway, there's nothing tricky here, it's a simple application of the l'Hospital rule.

Comment: As far as I read it from the beginning it was always $\;x^2\;$ , but perhaps the OP himself change it almost immediately after posted.

Answer (score 3):

Using l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2xe^{x^2}+\sin x}{2\sin x\cos x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2e^{x^2}+4x^2e^{x^2}+\cos x}{2\cos^2x-2\sin^2x}=\frac{2+0+1}{2}=\frac32$$

Comment: So far the only non-Taylor answer here. Hooray!

Comment: @Jack It may be cultural. In France, I was mostly trained with Taylor series (or "[développements limités](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9)"), and L'Hospital's rule was rather disregarded. I see Taylor series as more systematic and more powerful.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I studied both methods in Israel, yet I have to say that I consider l'Hospital as the fastest, easiest and, in general, best method when appliable. Of course, sometimes doing some limits *without* l'H helps to develop certain skills (trigonometric identities, algebraic manipulation), etc.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Taylor before LHR? What about those 0^0 things?

Comment: @jack Usually not a problem with $a^b=\exp(b \log a)$ and either Taylor, or basic limits such as $x^\alpha \log^\beta x$. When I was a student I have actually *never* used L'Hospital's rule. Not that it's that bad, but I prefered other tools, and it was taught that way anyway.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ayt. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\cdots=\frac{\dfrac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}}{\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2}+\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}$$

Use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1=\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u$ for the first part

and as $x\to0,\cos x\to1\implies\cos x-1\ne0$ for the second

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, Please revert the wrong rectification

Comment: Well, I don't see your point then. The fraction with cosines has a removable singularity, and it disappears when you cancel the common factor.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, As $1-\cos x\ne0$ it can be cancelled safely

Comment: Ah, ok. Actually, it's not completely true: when you compute a limit as $x\rightarrow a$, you have also to consider the case $x=a$ (but see below). Here it cancels safely not because the denominator is not zero, but because the numerator is also zero, and there is a common factor, leaving only $1+\cos x$. But it's not wrong either: there is a known difference between french "limite" and english "limit" (which is usually "limite épointée" in french). And here the difference is important.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have to disagree with your comment in the first line: when considering limits as $\;x\to a\;$ we **must** disregard as principle the case $\;x=a\;$ and, in fact, it is "our right *and duty*" to assume $\;x\;$ gets arbitraritly close to $\;a\;$ yet it never actually reaches it. Many texts use this: Purcell et al., Strang, Stewart, Spivak, etc. Some even stress this by requiring $\;0<|x-a|<\delta\;$ in the definition.

Comment: @Timbuc That's what I explain later in my comment: In France, usually the definition is not the same. And actually, the french definition is equivalent to continuity, when the function is defined for $x=a$. For this reason, you may consider the "english" definition is more useful. Still, it's called "limite épointée" in french. And I often forget to consider this on MSE. It's one of the few (many?) differences in mathematical notation between countries.

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor expansion. As $x\rightarrow0$, you have

$$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+O(x^4)$$
$$\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+O(x^4)$$
$$\sin^2x=x^2+O(x^4)$$

Thus

$$\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{1+x^2-1+\frac12x^2+O(x^4)}{x^2+O(x^4)}=\frac{\frac32+O(x^2)}{1+O(x^2)}\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} \frac32$$

Answer (score 1):

As Jean-Claude Arbaut showed, Taylor expansions are extremely useful for this kind of problems.

But, using them with a few more terms, you also see how is the limit approached $$A=\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{\Big(1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+O\left(x^6\right)\Big)-\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)\Big)}{x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)}$$ $$A\approx\frac{\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{11 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)}{x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)}=\frac{\frac{3 }{2}+\frac{11 x^2}{24}}{1-\frac{x^2}{3}}$$ Performing the long division, we have $$A\approx \frac{3}{2}+\frac{23 }{24}x^2$$ If you plot on the same graph the function and the above approximation, you will probably be amazed to see how close to each other are the two curves for $-\frac 12\leq x \leq \frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor series as

> $$\dfrac{e^{x^2} - \cos x}{\sin^2 x} \sim_{x\sim 0}  \dfrac{(1+x^2) - (1-x^2/2)}{x^2} =\frac{3}{2}. $$