# What did I do wrong trying to find this limit?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228251/98587), a user asked to find:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\exp(x^2)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^2}$$
I thought I could use pure trigonometric identities to find the limit. Apparently I was mistaken, but I can't find my mistake. Here's what I did:

Knowing $\sin(x)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$:
$$\frac{\exp(x^2)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^2} = \frac{\exp(x^2)-\cos(x)}{\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}} = \frac{\exp(x^2)-\cos(x)}{1} \cdot \frac{2}{1-\cos(2x)}$$
$$ = \frac{2(\exp(x^2)-\cos(x))}{1-\cos(2x)}$$
And knowing $\cos(2x) = 2\cos(x)^2-1$:
$$\frac{2(\exp(x^2)-\cos(x))}{1-\cos(2x)} = \frac{2(\exp(x^2)-\cos(x))}{1-(2\cos(x)^2-1)} = \frac{2(\exp(x^2)-\cos(x))}{-2(\cos(x)^2)}$$
$$ = -1 \cdot \frac{\exp(x^2)-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)^2} = -1 \cdot \left( \frac{\exp(x^2)}{cos(x)^2} -\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)^2} \right)
= -1 \cdot \left( \frac{\exp(x^2)}{cos(x)^2} -\frac{1}{cos(x)} \right) $$
And we can plug in $x=0$ since we don't run the risk of an indeterminate form:
$$ -1 \cdot \left( \frac{\exp(0^2)}{cos(0)^2} -\frac{1}{cos(0)} \right)  = -1 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1^2} -\frac{1}{1} \right) = -1 \cdot 0 = 0$$

Apparently the correct answer is $3/2$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $1-(2\cos(x)^2-1)=2-2\cos(x)^2\neq -2\cos(x)^2$

Comment: can you explain to me why you converted $\sin^2 x$ to $\cos^2 x$ via the double angle formulae rather than the straight forward $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$? as the previous comment states you also got the identity wrong.

Comment: @Chinny84 Because it looked like the inequality to use, in a bizarro-world where 1+1 = 0.

Comment: We have all been there. I remember once going through I whole calculation where I thought the identity for the relationship of $\cosh^2 ,\sinh^2 x$ was the same for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$. That was an annoying few hours of my life..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong step is $1-(2\cos^2x-1)=2-2\cos^2x\neq -2\cos^2x$.

Notice that you are simply itroducing double angle, then removing it, so it's equivalent to use the identity $\cos^2x +\sin^2x=1$.

Comment: As it turns out, 1+1 = 2, not 0